# Angular 2 Http get not triggering

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-http

As said in the title, nothing is happening when I subscribe to my observable. There is no error in the console or during the build. Here is my code :

**My service**

```
  getBlueCollars(): Observable<BlueCollar[]> {
return this.http.get(this.defaultAPIURL + 'bluecollar?limit=25').map(
  (res: Response) => {
    return res.json();
  });
}
```

**My component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.planifRequestService.getBlueCollars().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.blueCollars = data;
        console.log('Inner Blue Collars', this.blueCollars);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
    console.log('Value BlueCollars : ', this.blueCollars);
}
```

So the second console.log is triggering with "Value BlueCollars : Undefined", and the log in my subscribe is never showed. As well, I can't see the request sent in the Networt tab of Chrome.

So I tried to simplify everything with the following code :

```
let response: any;
this.http.get('myUrl').subscribe(data => response = data);
console.log('TestRep: ', response);
```

Same problem here, no error, response is undefined. It seems the subscribe is not triggering the observable. (The URL is correct, it is working on my swagger or with postman.)

I'm on Angular 2.4.9

**Edit**

So I tried to copy/past the code of my request on a brand new project, everything is working fine. The request is triggered and I can get the JSON response correctly. So there is something maybe on the configuration of my project that is forbiding the request to trigger correctly.

Comment: What is the URL of your Angular app what is the URL of the backend you are calling? Do they have the same host and port or not?

Comment: can we see the rest of the component code? or a plunkr?

Comment: the syntax of the subscribe is correct as far as i can see - subscribe can take one two or three functions as arguments, and the OP has two, which is fine.

Comment: I'm running the application localy while the backend is on a distant server. I tried to launch chrom with --disable-web-security --user-data-dir arguments to disable CORS but still not working. I tried the request in an empty component, but same problem.

Comment: if you don't see anything red anywhere in the console anyway it's not a cors problem I think

Comment: @Sebas, that's why I retracted my flag when realized it ;)

Comment: @SaHagin, try the fetch api instead to be completely sure. Don't observe it (it doesnt return an observable), just call the service, and see if you get anything back at least. A good thing would be for you to paste your imports as everybody here is supposing you're using ng2 Http... but maybe you aren't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok just found what was going on. I am using a fake backend in order to try my login connexions that is supposed to catch only specified URL. However for wathever raison it was catching all the requests, so that explain everything. Thx for your help everybody.

Comment: hi sa hagin  me too same problem   finally i have now fixed the problem cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a catch block to your service code:

```
getBlueCollars(): Observable<BlueCollar[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.defaultAPIURL + 'bluecollar?limit=25')
  .map(
    (res: Response) => {
      return res.json();
    })
  .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
}
```

Don't forget to

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`
```

I imagine this will result in the error that'll give you an idea where your code is going wrong.

Comment: Thx for your answere. I tried to add the catch with the good imports but nothing is happening. No errors are showing up.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `console.log` outside the subscribe call is undefined is because the subscribe/http call is happening **asynchronously** and so, in effect, the order (in time!) the code is running is:

1) the observable is subscribed to (and then waits for a response)
2) the outer console log runs with blueCollars undefined
3) when the response (or error) comes back from the http request (potentially after several seconds), only then will the inner assignment of `this.blueCollar = data` happen (and the inner console log), OR an error will get logged

Apart from that the subscribe code looks fine...!

Comment: Well, I understand but I should at least be able to see the request in the chrome network tab, wich is not the case. As well, I should see the 'Inner Blue Collars' in the console and that is not the case.

Comment: Sorry, the real problem is that obviously the subscribe callback does not show the log it should. The asynchronous part is correct but it does not explain the main issue.

Comment: yeah, I know, but I can't see any problems with the subscribe callback as it's set up